# How to pass a lastpass Vault object into multiprocessing process worker

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, lastpass

I am trying to run multiple processes all of which use information from my Lastpass credentials. The idea is to grab the Vault once, and then use a bunch of Workers retrieving passwords to do their jobs.

I get the vault -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    LPV=lp.get_vault()
```

I Define workers:

```
def workerDEV():
   environment='DEV'
   print "I am in ", environment
   create_objects.main(client=client, LastPassVault=LPV)

def workerPRD():
   environment='PRD'
   print "I am in ", environment
   create_objects.main(client=client, LastPassVault=LPV)
```

Launch the workers:

```
worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=workerDEV)
worker_1.start()

worker_2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=workerPRD)
worker_2.start()
```

I get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'LPV' is not defined
```

This makes sense, since as per my research, each worker re starts the session, thus loosing LPV, which is protected by `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

I looked into `multiprocessing.Value(typecode_or_type, *args, lock=True)`, but can't figure out how to use it. It seems like it is meant for objects of type String and Int, but not a Vault.

Thank you, and recommendations from here are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just pass `LPV` as argument to the process?

Comment: Tried that, but then nothing happens in parallel. It just launches the first worker, and waits for it to finish.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the code in which you passed the arguments ? And you cannot use `Vault` type objects with `Value`, just the types which are in `ctypes`

Comment: Thanks. So I tired passing the Vault, as so:
Process(target=target=workerDEV(), args=(LPV)). Got an error. Which is what you said not to do. 

Then I tried passing it like so:
 worker_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=workerDEV(LPV)- it worked, but only one worker launched. Others did nothing. 

Is that what you mean by adding my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this as your worker function to remove redundancy and pass LPV as a parameter to your worker function.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def workerFunc(num, LPV): 
    print "I am in ", num 
    create_objects.main(client=client, LastPassVault=LPV)

for i in range(2): 
    Process(target=workerFunc, args=(i, LPV)).start()
```